# Laravel findorfail() redirect

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code :

```
public function showTestProfile($id){
    $auth = Auth::user();
    $tests = App\Test::findorfail($id);
    return view('profile',compact('auth','tests','members'));
}
```

if we have an `id` in the DB table then that will come up with `findorfail()`,

but if we add not existing `id` to the url like this :

`http://NewPro.dev/user-profile/24645645456`

Then no query can be found and laravel page comes up.

How can I redirect to some route if we have no `id`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your uses in your controller

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;//find or fail error exception class.
```

and modify you current code to this

```
 public function showTestProfile($id){
    try{
        $auth = Auth::user();
        $tests = App\Test::findorfail($id);
        return view('profile',compact('auth','tests','members'));
    }
    catch(ModelNotFoundException $err){
        //if id doesnt exist it will skip return view('profil..
        //and excute whatever in this section
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `findOrFail()` with `find()` then `$tests` will be `null` when `id` doesn't exist.

```
public function showTestProfile($id)
{
    $auth = Auth::user();
    $tests = App\Test::find($id);

    if (is_null($tests)) {
        return redirect()->to('index');
    }

    return view('profile', compact('auth', 'tests', 'members'));
}
```

The below process is better than the above process.

```
public function showTestProfile($id)
{
    try {
        $auth = Auth::user();
        $tests = App\Test::findOrFail($id);
        return view('profile', compact('auth', 'tests', 'members'));
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $err) {
        //if id doesnt exist it will skip return view('profil..
        //and excute whatever in this section
        //import ModelNotFoundException class to work
    }
}
```