# Laravel firstOrFail functions redirects to wrong route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, exception, request

Info: All my routes look like this `/locale/something` for example `/en/home`
works fine.

In my controller I'm using the `firstOrFail()` function.

When the fail part is triggered the function tries to send me to `/home`.
Which doesn't work because it needs to be `/en/home`.

So how can I adjust the `firstOrFail()` function to send me to `/locale/home` ?
What needs to changed ?

Comment: Fail throws an exception which is then handled in the `Exceptions\Handler` class and it shows an error page. So you probably are handling this yourself and redirecting to `home` instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458579/laravel-findorfail-redirect seems like it would help you out

Comment: Normally it would return a 404 without redirecting to another url. Check your Exception Handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat it in several ways.

### Specific approach

You could surround your query with a try-catch wherever you want to redirect to a specific view every time a record isn't found:

```
 class MyCoolController extends Controller {

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

   //

    function myCoolFunction() {
        try
        {
            $object = MyModel::where('column', 'value')->firstOrFail();
        }
        catch (ModelNotFoundException $e)
        {
            return Redirect::to('my_view');
            // you could also:
            // return redirect()->route('home');
        }

        // the rest of your code..
    }

  }
```

The only downside of this is that you need to handle this everywhere you want to use the `firstOrFail()` method.

### The global way

As in the comments suggested, you could define it in the [Global Exception Handler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#the-exception-handler):

**app/Exceptions/Handler.php**

```
# app/Exceptions/Handler.php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

// some code..

public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException && ! $request->expectsJson())
    {
        return Redirect::to('my_view');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: @q55awr glad to help.